# Magento Import/export issue

Tags: magento, profile

I am currently trying to export 'all products' via the run profile. However an error is returned.

**Request Timeout**

This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

If someone could help me that would be great!

Thank You

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: @PiTheNumber that doesn't make it off topic for Stackoverflow though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase your execution time limit

`php.ini` in your magento root  with this setting:

```
max_execution_time = 1800
```

Also modify the memory limit allocated to php when using Magento

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

Alternatively you can edit `index.php`, if you don't have `php.ini` access.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800);
```