# Does magento return 20,000 products by single export file

Tags: magento

I need to export my all products, i get error like no data valid sent, or using data flow i get 500 internal server error, does magento return 20,000 products by single export file

Comment: It took me forever, but I exported 300k, so it does work

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity that would be the right place if he had not asked the same question there a dozen times, wasting everyones time and eventually got banned for low quality content (which is quite an extraordinary achievement over there)

Comment: I've since been invited to chat, added on LinkedIn and Skype. Regretting an "answer" now.

Answer (score 1):

> i get error like no data valid sent, or using data flow i get 500 internal server error

This is a timeout on your web server. You can increase your max execution time to fix this.

> does magento return 20,000 products by single export file

Magento exports whichever products you've selected from the admin product grid. If you've selected five, it will export five. If you've selected 100,000, it will export 100,000.

Yes, they go into a single file in the `var/export` directory.

---

It sounds like you simply need to increase your max execution time. See [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70797/fatal-error-time-out-when-trying-to-export-customers-from-magento-1-3-1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890863/magento-import-export-issue).

Comment: @ Robbie Averill : just suggest me the max-exe-time, i have set 2048 is my  site.

Comment: @ Robbie Averill  : am set max_exe_time=6048, still am get "no valid data send error", pls help me